# Linenumber doesn't work?

Tags: math-mode, numbering, line

I am using these packages to write a scientific paper. MWE

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,showpacs,floatfix,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{
        Is Justin Bieber a good singer?}
            
    \maketitle
    
    
    \section{Introduction} 
    

    
\end{document}
```

I am trying to find a way to number the lines of my paper.

I have tried  `\usepackage{lineno}` and `\linenumbers` but it messes up completely my file.

Without `\linenumbers`:

[image]

with `\linenumbers`

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Please extend your code to a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it helps and we can see exactly your setup etc, you can use the `lipsum` package for dummy text. Also, can you edit into your question an image/description of how it messes up your file please? Might be caused by a package or the class etc, is better to troubleshoot if we know the issue it is causing in your MWE or main document

Comment: @JamesT I have edited my question

Comment: Is it possible to use `revtex4-2` instead? That compiles with no issues, probably `revtex4` is out of date and updates to packages/latex kernal have broken it. My code looks fine if you use 4-2 instead and can be seen here https://imgur.com/a/QEkrMlI

Comment: You're specifying `aps,prl` so should almost certainly be using `revtex4-2`